# Javascript game Create new objects automatically to add into an array continuously [javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am pretty new to Javascript games, So please don't mind if this is an obvious question.
I have been trying to work on a frogger game. For this I have an object, And I just want to create new constructors consistently, so that it should look like as if a hoard of bugs are coming continuously.

This is my Enemy object.

```
    // Enemies our player must avoid
var Enemy = function(x,y) {
    // Variables applied to each of our instances go here,
    // we've provided one for you to get started

    // The image/sprite for our enemies, this uses
    // a helper we've provided to easily load images
    this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
    this.x = x;
    this.y =y;
};

// Update the enemy's position, required method for game
// Parameter: dt, a time delta between ticks
Enemy.prototype.update = function(dt) {
    // You should multiply any movement by the dt parameter
    // which will ensure the game runs at the same speed for
    // all computers.

   this.x = this.x+((Math.random() * (15 - 1 + 1) + 1)*dt*35);

   this.y = this.y;
};

// Draw the enemy on the screen, required method for game
Enemy.prototype.render = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
};
```

And then i push them manually into an Array

```
    // Place all enemy objects in an array called allEnemies
var allEnemies=[];
allEnemies.push(new Enemy(0,135))
allEnemies.push(new Enemy(0,225))
allEnemies.push(new Enemy(0,50))
```

I can only see a single column of bugs. I want this above scenario to happen automatically, I figured I need to use call function here, but I still need to do that automatically at continuous interval I prefer.

Comment: You can use setInterval if you want that to happen at continous intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `window.setInterval()` like Joachim says, or use `window.requestAnimationFrame()` or even use `window.setTimeout()`. I personally recommend use `requestAnimationFrame()` with browsers because it is specifically for drawing animations and rendering, but if you're doing something in the node environment, you should just go with `setInterval`.

Other than that, I saw that you push all new instances of Enemy to an array, you could do this with one added statement.
You could also push to an array whenever you create an object like so:

```
var allEnemies = [];

function Enemy(x,y){
    this.x = x || (Math.random() * WIDTH) | 0;
    this.y = y || (Math.random() * height) | 0;
    this.sprite = "bug-sprite-thing";
    allEnemies.push(this); // this is called every time you do `new Enemy(n,n)
    // the new object will automatically be pushed to the array.
}
```

If You want to spawn a new enemy at random intervals, you could use `setTimeout`

```
var MINIMUM = 100; // 0.1 seconds
var MILLISECONDS = 10000; // 10 seconds
function spawnAtRandom(){
    // add your code here.
    setTimeout(spawnAtRandom, minimum + (Math.random() * (MILLISECONDS-MINIMUM)));
}
spawnAtRandom();
```

What this function does is spawn one thing at the start, and then proceeds to spawn something in random intervals between `MINUMUM` and `MILLISECONDS`

Comment: But how will I call new Enemy at random intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `window.setInterval()`:

```
var allEnemies = [];
window.setInterval(function () {
  allEnemies.push(new Enemy(0, 135));
}, 2000);
```

This will create a new `Enemy` object in your array every 2 seconds at the same position (which you could randomize as well).